# How do I encrypt an Okio BufferedSource?

Tags: android, encryption, okhttp, okio

Due to HIPAA requirements, I need to encrypt data at rest. I have a `BufferedSource` that contains data from my api call.

The Okio documentation says

> Sinks may be layered to transform received data, such as to compress, encrypt, throttle, or add protocol framing.

How do I use a `Sink` to perform this encryption?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment Okio doesn’t have anything built-in. Easiest is to use `BufferedSource.writeTo(Sink)` to write your plaintext to an encrypted sink, which you can create using `Okio.sink(OutputStream)`.

If you get a complete example working I'd love to use it  as an example on the Okio GitHub page.